# With swiper counsel ivy installed I get a 4 digit number in front of M-x in the mini-buffer. What does this number relate to?

Tags: ivy, counsel, swiper

It doesn’t seem to be related either to the line I am in nor to the number of chars in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to `ivy-count-format`. From the [manual](https://oremacs.com/swiper/#defcustoms):

> A string that specifies display of number of candidates and current
> candidate, if one exists.

You can customize it if the default value does not suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your help.